# SQL Server how to tell if a value changed

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-date-functions

I have a table with three columns:

```
Date, Symbol, Rankings
```

How can list all the symbols whose rank changed from yesterday to today?

I can get today's values easily:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [date], [symbol], [ranking]
FROM 
    [Rankings].[dbo].[Rankings]
WHERE
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), date, 102) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102)
ORDER BY 
    symbol DESC
```

Comment: Why on earth are you converting your dates to string - just to compare? Hoping that the column `Date` is of `DATETIME` datatype (as it should be), you could much more easily do a `CAST(date AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` and avoid converting everything to a string .....

Comment: Date is of type DATETIME. Yep, I can do a date compare.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
  SELECT TOP (1000) r1.[date]
     ,r1.[symbol]
     ,r1.[ranking]
  FROM [Rankings].[dbo].[Rankings] r1
  INNER JOIN [Rankings].[dbo].[Rankings] r2 ON (
      r1.symbol = r2.symbol
      AND DateAdd(dd, 1, CONVERT(date, r1.date)) = CONVERT(date, r2.date)
      AND r1.ranking != r2.ranking
      )
  order by r1.symbol desc
```

Note that I am doing a date compare not string representation of a date compare

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'r1'.

Comment: I fixed the not equal and dates

Comment: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'date'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'symbol'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Ambiguous column name 'ranking'.

Comment: Now runs. I have to verify that it is doing the right thing next.

Comment: BTW, date if of type Datetime, which I misled you on.

Comment: I am thinking date field is really a datetime or similar type. The conversion is necessary so that only date part of date [sic] is being compared.

Answer (score 1):

You can `GROUP BY` `[symbol]` and with condition `min(ranking)` not equal to `max(ranking)`

```
SELECT
    [symbol],
    MAX(CASE WHEN [date] = CONVERT(date, getdate() - 1) THEN [ranking] END) AS yesterday,
    MAX(CASE WHEN [date] = CONVERT(date, getdate()) THEN [ranking] END) AS today
FROM 
    [Rankings]
WHERE
    [date] >= CONVERT(date, getdate() - 1)
AND [date] <= CONVERT(date, getdate())
GROUP BY 
    [symbol]
HAVING  
    MIN([ranking])  <> MAX([ranking])
ORDER BY 
    [symbol] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried below code in SQL Server. It works. The advantage of below approach is that, it avoids usage of functions in the WHERE clause, which leads to sargeable queries. If the Date column is having the proper index, the below query will give good performance.

```
CREATE TABLE #rankings(symbol CHAR(10), [date] DATETIME, RANKING INT);

INSERT INTO #rankings VALUES ('MSFT','20190922', 1), ('MSFT','20190923',2), ('AMZN', '20190922', 3), ('AMZN','20190923',3);

DECLARE @todayStart DATETIME = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
DECLARE @yesterDayStart DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY,-1,@todaystart)
SELECT @todayStart, @yesterDayStart


SELECT today.symbol, yesterday.ranking, today.ranking
FROM (SELECT * FROM #Rankings AS today WHERE today.date >= @todayStart) AS today
JOIN (SELECT * FROM #Rankings AS yesterday WHERE yesterday.date >= @yesterdayStart AND yesterday.date < @todayStart) AS yesterday
ON today.symbol = yesterday.symbol 
WHERE today.ranking <> yesterday.ranking
```

Comment: The query optimizer is clever enough to use an index for `DateTime` columns cast as `Date`, e.g. `... where Cast( [date] as Date ) = Cast( GetDate() as Date );` to get today's rows. (An old reference is [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).)

Comment: @HABO, Thanks for the reference. I was not aware of it.